# Microphone on Sennheiser PC360 not recording input

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, microphone

I've recently built a new system with an Asus Z87-pro motherboard and gone through a large system install. I have installed Realtek HD Audio Manager and everything but my microphone works fine. Some details;

- The microphone works. I tested it using my laptop, and it records audio correctly.
- Realtek shows I have the device plugged in
- Audio Output works fine, so I'm sure I installed the drivers correctly

Is there something im missing?

Comment: Ok, was doing some trouble shooting, and something very weird happened. After reversing the ports (Headphone jack went into microphone jack, and vice versa), I told realtek the differences, boosted it by 30 DB, and my mates could hear me on skype. Tried it with the default ports, and they couldn't hear me at all. This is truly strange.

Comment: Ok, got it working with default jacks by boosting with 30 DB, but my mates still say it is quite quiet, so I dont count this as a fixed problem. Would still appreciate help.